# Finding header/title of nearest number from a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel]

Goal is to find the heading/title of a cell matching exactly with a other cell from the same row. In the above image the pink data is available, the user inputs in the green field and the function should show the output in the blue column; i.e From the first pink row the number 12 matches with the last pink column of the same row which has a heading/title as 2021Rating and it is shown. Similarly for the last row the number 15 does not exist in the same row as a result NOT FOUND is shown.

This task somehow can be accomplished with formula like =IF(B2=G2,"2017Rating", IF(C2=G2,"2018Rating...) but is there any better way ?
What if I want the closest match with threshold value of x% in case exact number is not found in the row ? (i.e instead of NOT FOUND the result should be 2017Rating as 14 closest to 15)

Comment: Try index() with match().

Comment: @SolarMike can you show some example ?

Comment: Lots of examples on here - have you not searched?

Comment: @SolarMike I tried so hard, got so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Excel-365` then can use `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(G2,B2:F2,$B$1:$F$1,"Not Found")
```

For other version of excel use `INDEX/MATCH` like

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$F$1,,MATCH(G2,B2:F2,0)),"Not Found")
```

Also `FILTER()` function will work like

```
=@FILTER($B$1:$F$1,B2:F2=G2,"Not Found")
```

[image]

Comment: The part 1 works perfectly. But is there any way to find the next closest number with a upper & lower bound of say 10% in case of NOT FOUND ?

Comment: You can use `next higher` or `next lower` value if not exact value found.

Comment: Please show some formula of next higher / next lower in older Excel [2010/2016] please

Comment: @www.friend0.in so add or subtract 1 or 1.5 from G2 in the xlookup() or match()...